# Login and authentication via C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was just wondering what were the best ways to write login and authentication in ASP.NET. To my knowledge, ways to authenticate are via:

- implementation of the ASP.NET Permissions Provider against SQL Server
- Writing your own function, starting a session for the user at login and clearing the session at logout.

Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

ASP.NET membership supports facilities for:

- Creating new users and passwords.
- Storing membership information (user names, passwords, and supporting data) in Microsoft SQL Server, Active Directory, or an alternative data store.
- Authenticating users who visit your site. You can authenticate users programmatically, or you can use the ASP.NET login controls to create a complete authentication system that requires little or no code.
- Managing passwords, which includes creating, changing, and resetting them . Depending on membership options you choose, the membership system can also provide an automated password-reset system that takes a user-supplied question and response.
- Exposing a unique identification for authenticated users that you can use in your own applications and that also integrates with the ASP.NET personalization and role-management (authorization) systems.
- Specifying a custom membership provider, which allows you to substitute your own code to manage membership and maintain membership data in a custom data store.

(Source: See top link.)

Comment: Hi mate, sorry by permissions provider, i meant membership provider. Any other sols?

Comment: The problem with Membership provider is that you need to adhere to the way Microsoft wants you to implement authentication.

Comment: Also, how about if you are going against a different database, e.g simply using an Access database compared to SQL Server

Comment: I believe you're not too experienced (yet) in ASP.NET, so I would advise you to stick with the built-in facilities. You can always create your own membership provider, either by following Microsoft's Membership system, or make your entire own authorization system later (grab username & password, check for equality against stored values in a database).

Comment: Btw, to clarify, the reason why I said you're not too experienced is that I made that assumption based on your question ;)

Comment: You'd sooner shoot yourself than using an access database.

Comment: One more: I made my own authentication system simply by taking in user+password, hashing, compare hash value against stored value in database, voila. I prefer doing it without the MS Membership Prov. overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default MembershipProvider for SQLServer, or if you want there is also an interface you can implement to roll your own custom MemberhipProvider.  The nice thing about doing it this way is there are controls that can consume such a provider.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the out of the box login controls all expect you to use a membership provider based solution - makes coding up some of those things very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Definately stick to the ASP.NET Membership provider model, else you'll spend more time 'fighting the defaults' then you will actually trying to solve your original problem.

If you really want to write your own provider have a look at the [Provider Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336558.aspx) on MSDN. Which includes a set of sample Access Database providers. Microsoft are not locking you into sql server with this, do a search on the net and you'll find providers for most databases. Including:

- [MySql](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+membership+providers)
- [Firebird](http://codemuch.com/node/4)
- [Oracle](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=asp.net+oracle+membership+providers)
- [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/vistadb3/features.aspx)
- [Sqlite](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=asp.net+sqlite+membership+providers)
- [Even](http://code.google.com/p/systembusinessobjects/) [NHibernate](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=asp.net+nhibernate+membership+providers)

Again, emphasizing everyones point so far, tell me what you can't do with this or that someone else has not already done?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad.

Yes, you can use the ASP.NET Membership provider.

Yes, you can use a 'session', on the server, and an identifier in the cookie or query string, to access that session, or you can do several other things.

It's hard to list 'all the ways', because you can effectively do whatever you want.

What sort of answer are you after, here?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a website for general public consider using OpenID. [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) should make it really easy.